# slider by Swiper js

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js, html5-history

This is an autoplay slider.I want to add  blur effect on the image which once is passed and the upcoming image but not the first image. how I can do that? I also want to target the dynamic style element by useing javascript.For example I want to target the z-index element

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
  effect: "coverflow",
  loop: true,
  grabCursor: true,
  centeredSlides: true,
  slidesPerView: "auto",
  coverflowEffect: {
    rotate: 20,
    stretch: 0,
    depth: 700,
    modifier: 1,
    slideShadows: true,
  },
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
  },
  autoplay: {
    delay: 1000,
    disableOnInteraction: false,
  },
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  ## ---------- 1. List item ##
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.swiper-slide {
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Swiper JS -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
<!-- Swiper -->
<div class="swiper-container mySwiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-4.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-5.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

you can also check it from [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/oomfr?file=/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can add filter: blur(3px) (for example) on all slides, and then set the active slide to filter: unset;

```
.swiper-slide { filter: blur(3px); }
.swiper-slide-active { filter: unset; }
```

You could target the active slide with JS with for example `document.querySelector('.swiper-slide-active').classList.add('my-z-index-class')`

(you need to add a CSS class with the name of .my-z-index-class for this example to work).